# Does a JIT compiler compile code statement-by-statement or method-by-method or the whole program in one go?

Tags: jit

I've read some articles and posts about what a JIT compiler does. Some were saying that a JIT compiler compiles the entire program before it is run, some were saying the JIT compiles "fragments" - without defining what a "fragment" is, some saying it compiles method-by-method. Some were saying it compiles each statement before executing it. But surely compiling the whole program before executing it would not be much different to normal compilation?

Which version is correct?

Comment: None of the answers there address the issue.

Comment: Which implementation of JIT you're referring to?

Comment: There are different types of JIT compilers. Some compile method by method, other (tracing) compile traces, which may be loops, methods, etc.

Comment: Where do I go to find a list of the different JIT compilers? When I search "types of jit compilers" I get only .NET compilers.

Answer (score 1):

When you compile a program from your IDE, you get an EXE made of intermediary language (IL) code. The JITter, which is platform-specific, turns this portable IL into native code (the local machine language).

In Java, the JIT compiler runs at method entry. Source:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15058/underst_jit.htm

.NET also JITs per method. Source:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there an exhaustive list of possible compilers such as method and trace JITs?